# How to stack vertically many buttons on an HTML table in a single row cell

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating and filling up an HTML table dynamically on AJAX callback with JavaScript.
My need would be to stack 3 buttons vertically on a single row cell.
I've tried with the standard:

```
var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn";
btn.value = "Test1";
```

And then appending these buttons to the pertaining  cell.
Actually this makes the buttons to be created on the same row, from left to right. My need would be to have them created vertically, instead.
May I use the button group option, setting its property to vertical?
I'm not sure if the button group can be used as a  child.

Comment: This is more a css issue

Comment: Use CSS `display: block;` to sack the buttons vertically.

Comment: You could also wrap each button in `<div>`

Comment: also, you should follow a CSS tutorial somewhere. Because you are asking trivial question and kind of wasting community time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Actually I'm not using CSS at all, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Apolo: if you are using your time in telling me I'm wasting your time, probably it really means you have some time to be wasted.

Answer (score 3):

There are few options:

1. Use `display: block`
2. Use floats and `clear: both;`
3. Use `<br/>` between buttons
4. Wrap each button with `<div>`

```css
#e1 button {
  display: block;
}

#e2 button {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#e2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#e1, #e2, #e3, #e4 {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="e1">
<button>button</button><button>button</button><button>button</button>
</div>
<div id="e2">
<button>button</button><button>button</button><button>button</button>
</div>
<div id="e3">
<button>button</button><br/>
<button>button</button><br/>
<button>button</button>
</div>
<div id="e4">
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think CSS is strictly needed to achieve this, but I will follow your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found a solution which doesn't involve CSS between buttons at all, as I was looking for.
As I told above, I'm building the table from within a HTTPRequest callback, in order to parse a returning XML with a dynamic number of children instead.
So, I cannot use any "static" html or "static" css.
The solution (at least the one I'd like the most), is simply to post-pone some br after the buttons, without any need of CSS decoration.
Here my trial javascript example:

```
var y = document.createElement("TR");
x.appendChild(y);

var z = document.createElement("TD");

var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn";
btn.value = "Test1";

z.appendChild(btn);
var br = document.createElement("br");
z.appendChild(br);

var btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = "button";
btn.className = "btn";
btn.value = "Test2";

z.appendChild(btn);
var br = document.createElement("br");
z.appendChild(br);

var t = document.createTextNode("MyCell");
z.appendChild(t);   

y.appendChild(z);
```

So, probably this is not the most "formal" solution ever, but it's enough flexible to fit my dynamic created table without bothering about CSS at all.

EDIT: thank to @Justinas for having pointed me out to the right direction with br's (which does not relate to CSS indeed).

Comment: I'd like to thank people who downvoted me twice. However, I'd like just to point out: 1) this was not a strictly CSS related question at all, as I demonstrated. 2) I really think my only mistake has been to omit from the title "...without using CSS", but when I realized it it was too late.